# Getting Method not found when running from Production but not from VB.Net 2015 IDE

Tags: vb.net

We have a desktop vb.net 2015 that has been running in production for a number of customers for several years.

In a recent update we made to the program we are now getting a Method not found for a method that should not even being invoked.

It does not fail in the IDE.

We have be log entry traces and can see where it crashes but the code does not invoke the method in the error message.

The code is invoice a method (not the failing method) and the one of the first things it does is to create a trace entry that it was entered. But this does not show in the log. It does have a log entry for the crash.

Crash message
Do Add Line err=438 Method not found: 'Int32 QBOAPIV3DT.QBAPIV3Cl.GetThisItemNdx(System.String ByRef, Int16, System.String ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.Object ByRef, Intuit.Ipp.Data.Item ByRef, Intuit.Ipp.Data.ItemTypeEnum ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Boolean ByRef, System.String ByRef, Int16 ByRef, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.String, Boolean ByRef, System.String ByRef, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ByRef, System.String ByRef)'

Note the fnDebug function just writes a log entry.

...

```
fnDebug("Do Add Line Doing Invoice Add (2) QBO=" & DoingQBOE & " B=" & B)  ' [[ 2018-12-03 B??? ]]
            WhereAT = "DAL, Invoice Invoice line "  ' [[ 2018-12-03 B??? ]]
            If Not InvoiceLineAddSub(pName:=CustomerNm, pItem:=pItem, pQty:=pQtyStr, pPrice:=pPriceStr, pAmt:=pAmtStr, pDesc:=Desc,
                        pServiceDate:=MyServiceDateStr, pLineClass:=pClass, pDoTax:=False, pPending:=(pPendingStr.ToUpper.StartsWith("T")),
                        pPO:=ThePONum, pBlankLine:=B, pOutReason:=pOutReason) Then
                i = i
                GoTo ExitFunction
            Else
...
End if
```

and in a separate module the fnDebug does not create a log entry

```
 Public Function InvoiceLineAddSub(ByVal pName As String, Optional ByVal pDate As String = "", Optional ByVal pPO As String = "", Optional pClass As String = NIL, _
            Optional ByVal pItem As String = "", Optional ByVal pQty As String = "", Optional ByVal pPrice As String = "", _
            Optional ByVal pAmt As String = "", Optional ByVal pDesc As String = "", _
            Optional ByVal pIsTaxableStr As String = "", Optional ByVal pServiceDate As String = NIL, _
            Optional ByVal pLineClass As String = NIL, Optional ByVal pCFAR As String = Nothing, _
            Optional ByVal pAccnt As String = NIL, Optional ByVal pDoTax As Boolean = True, _
            Optional ByVal pPending As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal pShipMethod As String = NIL, _
            Optional ByVal pGroup As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal pTaxCode As String = NIL, _
            Optional ByVal pUOM As String = NIL, Optional ByVal pBlankLine As Boolean = False, _
            Optional ByVal pToEmail As Boolean = False, Optional pToPrint As Boolean = False, _
            Optional ByRef pOutInItemListId As String = NIL, _
            Optional ByRef pOutReason As String = NIL) As Boolean
        Dim i As Short
        Dim Ss, s, Sss As String
        Dim FunRC As Boolean
        Dim Dbl As Double
        On Error GoTo ErrX
        fnDebug("Invoice Line Add Sub Entered name=" & pName & " Email=" & pToEmail & " Print=" & pToPrint & " Item=" & pItem & " QBO=" & DoingQBOE)

...
End Function
```

Again, it does not fail in the ide and this app has been working for a long time.

Any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Is the .pdb file up to date, if there is one?

Comment: There are 2 pdb files. One is for an obsolete class that has been replaced. The newer one that replaced the older has an old date. But these are in the code output folder. There are no pdb files in the program files (x86) folder where it actually runs starts from.

Comment: I rebuilt the project in VS 2017 and have the same exact problem. Works in IDE but not after the install.  We do use the Setup and Deploy project.

Comment: Does it work with "xcopy deployment" by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by removing the DLL (that should not even have to invoked) and then re-adding it again.

Since this DLL was not supposed to be used at all for this run it is very unclear as to why.  So if anyone can tell me why an DLL class is being invoked when the code is not telling it to be invoked I would really appreciate it.

Since I have 'fixed' the issue I am marking this answered but I may open another question as to why this happened.